# Altering a Table to Add a Column thats Value is set using a UPDATE JOIN Query

Tags: mysql

Im trying to create a Column thats Value is defined through anUPDATE JOIN SET statement. The exact question that im trying to answer actually is

"Add to a relational table EMPLOYEE information about the total number of orders handled by each employee. Note, that if an employee handled no orders then for such employee the total number of orders must be set to zero. Enforce the appropriate consistency constraints on a relational table EMPLOYEE. "

```
    ALTER TABLE EMPLOYEE
    ADD TOTALNUMBER VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL;

    UPDATE EMPLOYEE E JOIN ORDERS O ON(E.EMPLOYEE_ID = O.EMPLOYEE_ID)
    SET E.TOTALNUMBER = E.EMPLOYEE_ID + O.ORDER_ID;


    UPDATE EMPLOYEE
    SET TOTALNUMBER = 0
    WHERE TOTALNUMBER IS NULL;
```

tables being used

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE
(
    EMPLOYEE_ID     DECIMAL(9)  NOT NULL,
    LASTNAME        VARCHAR(20)     NOT NULL,
    FIRSTNAME       VARCHAR(10)     NOT NULL,
    TITLE       VARCHAR(30),
    TITLE_OF_COURTESY   VARCHAR(25),
    BIRTHDATE       DATE,
    HIREDATE        DATE,
    ADDRESS         VARCHAR(60),
    CITY        VARCHAR(15),
    REGION      VARCHAR(15),
    POSTAL_CODE     VARCHAR(10),
    COUNTRY         VARCHAR(15),
    HOME_PHONE      VARCHAR(24),
    EXTENSION       VARCHAR(4),
    PHOTO       VARCHAR(255),
    NOTES       VARCHAR(2000),
    REPORTS_TO      DECIMAL(9),
    CONSTRAINT PK_EMPLOYEE PRIMARY KEY (EMPLOYEE_ID)
);
```

```
CREATE TABLE ORDERS
(
    ORDER_ID        DECIMAL(9)  NOT NULL,
    CUSTOMER_CODE   VARCHAR(5)  NOT NULL,
    EMPLOYEE_ID     DECIMAL(9)  NOT NULL,
    ORDER_DATE      DATE        NOT NULL,
    REQUIRED_DATE   DATE,
    SHIPPED_DATE    DATE,
    SHIP_VIA        VARCHAR(40),
    FREIGHT         DECIMAL(10,2)           DEFAULT 0,
    SHIP_NAME       VARCHAR(40),
    SHIP_ADDRESS    VARCHAR(60),
    SHIP_CITY       VARCHAR(15),
    SHIP_REGION     VARCHAR(15),
    SHIP_POSTAL_CODE    VARCHAR(10),
    SHIP_COUNTRY    VARCHAR(15),
    CONSTRAINT PK_ORDERS PRIMARY KEY (ORDER_ID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_CUSTOMER_CODE FOREIGN KEY (CUSTOMER_CODE) REFERENCES CUSTOMER(CUSTOMER_CODE),  
    CONSTRAINT FK_EMPLOYEE_ID FOREIGN KEY (EMPLOYEE_ID) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE(EMPLOYEE_ID),  
    CONSTRAINT FK_SHIP_VIA FOREIGN KEY (SHIP_VIA) REFERENCES SHIPPER(COMPANY_NAME)  
);
```

Im unsure of what the exact result should be but i recieve a total of 9 rows with values ranging between 252 to 296. It doesnt seem to odd that an employee would deal with this many Orders but it seems to be too small of a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't recommend your current approach, and the best way to determine the number of orders per employees is to just aggregate and join, without storing this number in the actual employee table.  That being said, if you want to proceed this way, then consider using this update query:

```
UPDATE EMPLOYEE e
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID, COUNT(*) AS num_orders
    FROM ORDERS
    GROUP BY EMPLOYEE_ID
) o
    ON e.EMPLOYEE_ID = o.EMPLOYEE_ID
SET TOTALNUMBER = COALESCE(o.num_orders, 0);
```

Or, you could use:

```
SET TOTALNUMBER = o.num_orders;
```

and then use your second update to zero-out the employee totals which had no orders at all:

```
UPDATE EMPLOYEE
SET TOTALNUMBER = 0
WHERE TOTALNUMBER IS NULL;
```

But note that this would require that the `TOTALNUMBER` columns is *not* nullable.  So you would need to remove the `NOT NULL` constraint.

Comment: @ Tim Beigeleisen  Thankyou!! it works. Is there another way to do the totalnumber without using COALESCE?

Comment: The call to `COALESECE` is critical here, and assigns a zero order count to any employee which had no orders whatsoever.  There are other ways of handling this, but what is your issue with using `COALESCE`?

Comment: Im unsure if im allowed to use that command. Would my orignal script to set it to 0 work?

Comment: Your current approach would work, but you would have to make the total column nullable, i.e. remove `NOT NULL` from the column definition.

Comment: Okay thankyou. One more question. It says to add a consistancy Constraint. Would that mean totalnumber would be a foreign key?

Comment: I have no idea what that means.  And the total number of orders column does not logically refer to any column in the orders table, as it is an aggregate of records.

Comment: It says the Query needs a Primary Key or a Foreign key

Comment: The primary key of the `EMPLOYEE` table is `EMPLOYEE_ID`.  And `EMPLOYEE_ID` is also a _foreign_ key in the `ORDERS` table.  This is really a second question you are asking now.  You should open a new question if you have a bunch of follow-ups.

Comment: I'm not a fan of OUTER JOINs on UPDATEs. Two updates will acheive the same thing.